# Pushing data to a JSON generated with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, json, object, push

In the following lines everything works if I don't try to push something to $dataJson.

```
    $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT Comp_Name,Comp_Email 
        FROM Company");

    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $dataJson = json_encode($donnees);
        $dataJson.push({Col1:'Company Name',Col2:'Email'});
        echo $dataJson;
    };
```

I want to add a last object to the array of object generated by json_encode.

I may be missing something easy since every tips I found on internet failed to solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: `$dataJson.push()` isn't PHP syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to call `fetchAll()` in a loop. It fetches all the results at once.

Next, you seem to be mixing Javascript syntax into your PHP. PHP doesn't use `.shift()` to add to an array, or `{}` as syntax for objects.

Next, you don't push onto the JSON, you push onto the array, then you encode the array as JSON.

If you want the column headings to be at the beginning of the array, you should use `array_unshift()`, not `array_push()`.

So it should be:

```
$donnees = $response->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
array_unshift($donnees, array('Col1' => 'Company Name', 'Col2' => 'Email'));
$dataJson = json_encode($donnees);
echo $dataJson;
```

Comment: While testing something after adding the loop I jumped to a wrong conclusion. It's indeed useless.
I do mix the syntax often, thank you.
I works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

json_encode converts an array into a string. You can't push anything to strings, and you you try to concatenate, you will not end up with invalid json. do this instead.

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT Comp_Name,Comp_Email 
        FROM Company");

$data=array();
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[]=$donnees;
};
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used the other solution but your answer helped me clear some misunderstanding too.